# Azure AD: Can't log in with Application after update

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

After updating our Video Communication System that can make calls over Skype For Business, it wasn't able to log onto Office 365 Anymore. Here is the Error-Message:

```html
The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '{identifier}'{namePhrase}. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

I haven't changed anything regarding the logon information, that password hasn't expired as well...after some I digging on google most people tell me to update the App Permissions...but the problem is that the App doesn't exist on the Azure Portal.... it also doesn't give me any more info when I check the Sign-In Logs of the User that is being used.

Do you guys may know what I have to do authorize this sign-in?

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

An application is registered in Azure AD. The important values are:

- Tenant id
- Application id

The problem is that the tenant that you are trying to log in to does not have the application id in your configuration.

But it worked before the update. Therefore, you need to check if these values were changed in the last deployment.